# Alterar HTML não reflete na página - Asp .NET Core 3.0

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, visual-studio

Recentemente resolvi testar o `ASP .Net core 3.0`, sempre alterei o HTML sem a necessidade de recompilar o projeto, porém nessa versão, não consigo alterar NADA no HTML sem a necessidade de recompilar o projeto inteiro, mesmo uma simples tag. Não encontrei nada na documentação sobre essa alteração, se é alguma configuração, ou algum erro na própria IDE, que teve que ser atualizada, antes eu utilizava o 
Visual Studio 2017, e na versão .Net Core 3.0, exige o Visual Studio 2019.

Teria alguma forma de alterar isso? Pois é muito inconveniente ter que recompilar para aplicar uma simples alteração de HTML.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você precisa instalar o **pacote** `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation` via nuget e depois configurar o serviço `AddRazorRuntimeCompilation` no **startup.cs**.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
}
```

Comment: Eu estava com o mesmo problema usando o .net 3.1 e o VS 2019. Fiz oq vc falou e parece ter resolvido.

Answer (score 2):

Isso é uma opção da IDE Visual Studio, não um recurso da linguagem.

Para habilitar vá siga os passos:

1. Abra o menu **Tools > Options (pt-br: Ferramenta / Opções)**
2. Clique na opção **Debugging (pt-br: Depuração)**
3. Localize a opção **Enable Edit and Continue (pt-br: Ativar Editar e
       Continuar)** e as opção filhas, conforme imagem abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

Acontece o mesmo comigo. Meu Visual Studio 2019 está com essas opções habilitadas e nada.

Uma solução que achei foi:
Com a view que deseja editar aberta.

File > View in Browser

ou pelo atalho atalho:
CTRL + SHIFT + W

Editei CSS e HTML e funcionou tranquilo, não testei com JS.

Answer (score 1):

Para resolver isso, edit o arquivo do seu projeto **.CSPROJ**, acrescentando a tag **RazorCompileOnPublish** e marcando com “false”:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]